# Left sidebar with expanding horizontal background?

Tags: html, css, response

Is it possible to have a sidebar that is connected to the left hand side of the browser only by a background image/colour however, whatever the browser size the content within remains to the right and the same distance from other content AND both content blocks centred?

[image: Like this image explains..]

I thought perhaps percentages, but its the relation to the right hand column which is causing issues..

Comment: Do you have your HTML/ CSS (on JSFiddle)? I don't totally understand. Do you want to align your complete website (with a fix width) on the right side? And then have the background filling up the room on the left?

Comment: Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/nickr/TWdXe/ ?

Comment: black color put on your body. and make .container{width:1004px; margin:0 auto;} tyr this css then you have your data center in any browser

Comment: Thank you Nick, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a long border and negative margins to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/TWdXe/2/

```
.outer {
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    width:650px;       // make your fixed container
    margin-left:auto;  // center it
    margin-right:auto; // center it
}
.inner {
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-left: solid 1000px red; // long border on the left  
     margin-left: -1000px;         // negative margin to keep the layout 
}
.foo {
    width:400px;
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    border-right: solid 1000px orange; // long border on the right - optional
    margin-right: -1000px;             // negative margin to keep the layout -  optional 
}


body {overflow:hidden;}  //Resolves horizontal scrollbar
```

Comment: Creative solution, but it gives the body a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: UPDATED - use body {overflow:hidden;}

Comment: OR dont use the long border on the right which is what his image shows.

Comment: overflow:hidden; also makes the vertical scrollbar disappear. Not using the right border is indeed a solution. If the wish to have a background there aswell, the TS could consider to set a BG image for the body.

Comment: Indeed you are right.  you could use overflow-x instead http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp